# Put List Into TextFile After line.split - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new at Python, using version 2.7.13 on my MBP. When I ran the code to print to the shell, it shows the result in the desired list. But when I write to a text file, the result is different. Any tips, pointers or hints? Below is the code:

```
import os
import re

filePath = "./ssh.log.txt"
fd = open(filePath, 'r')
writeFile = "./origin.txt"
sf = open(writeFile, "w")
sf.write("[scan origin hosts]")
#print "[scan origin hosts]"

with fd as reader :
    for line in reader :
        if "success" in line:
            sf.write (line.split('  ')[2])
            #print (line.split('    ')[2])
```

The output to text file should look like how it is seen in the Python shell

[image]

Comment: you forgot the `\n` char! `print` adds linefeed `write` doesn't. try `sf.write("\n")` in your loop

Comment: the text file looks the same to me it just does not have new lines or any delimiters to separate the data.

Comment: Because `print` and `write` work differently. If your loop already works with `print`, you could always just use the `file` argument to `print`, so `print(line.split('    ')[2], file=sf)`

Comment: In order to use juanpa.arrivillaga's suggestion in Python 2 you will need to disable the `print` _statement_ so you can use the `print` _function_.  To do that, put this at the top of your `import` statements: `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: BTW, In the `write` call you're splitting on 2 spaces, but in the `print` statement you're splitting on 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard, just change

```
with fd as reader :
for line in reader :
    if "success" in line:
        sf.write (line.split('  ')[2])
        #print (line.split('    ')[2])
```

To

```
with fd as reader :
for line in reader :
    if "success" in line:
        sf.write (line.split('  ')[2]+"\n")
        #print (line.split('    ')[2])
```

This error is due to the fact that the write function outputs the exact contents of the string to the file, while python's print function adds a newline at the end of the string before printing it to the shell.

Comment: I added the "\n" in the script and viola! That did the trick!

Comment: Im glad it helped